# Веб-приложение, архитектура, логика, Java, Servlet, EL, JSP, HTML, SQL, JDBC и Геркулесовая каша в голове. У всех так было поначалу?

Tags: java, sql, jsp, servlet, jdbc

**Прошу сообщество помочь мне в собрании пазла из всех этих технологий, понятий, разработок пестрящих в сети и уложить в моей голове понимание работы простого веб – приложения (клиент – сервер – БД).**

Использую Tomcat 8, IntellijIDEA Ultimate,

Думаю, для новичков это будет полезно. Буду использовать обычные слова и термины, И ВСЕХ КОММЕНТАТОРОВ ПРИЗЫВАЮ К ЭТОМУ!!! ИЗЛАГАТЬ ТЕХНИЧЕСКИМ СЛЕНГОМ, ЭТО ДЕЛО ОПЫТА, НОВИЧКУ ОТ ЭТОГО ПОНАЧАЛУ ПОЛЬЗЫ НЕ БУДЕТ!!!

Вкратце видение автора на все это:

> 1. Молодая девушка заходит на сайт компании «Bentley» и заполняет форму «Получить красный Bentley Bentayga в подарок», кликает
>      «Получить»;
> 2. код формы HTML в JSP(index.jsp) отправляет запрос на сервер (ServletBentley);
> 3. в ServletBentley класс (Class Select) с кодом DAO отправляет запрос «красный Bentley Bentayga» в БД;
> 4. Девушке повезло!) в БД красный Bentley Bentayga имеется;
> 5. о чем Class Select сообщает ServletBentley;
> 6. сервер ServletBentley доносит эту новость в JSP(index.jsp);
> 7. Девушка счастлива!!!

Вот такая каша в моей голове!) Как по вашему как данная логика должна быть реализована?

Comment: Вам стоит сначала хорошо разобраться с общими принципами программирования и освоить java core. Последовательное системное освоение технологий позволит избежать каши в голове.

Comment: Добрый день Сергей, спасибо за помощь, еще за прошлый вопрос. Теория Java Core и синтаксис был пройден, как говориться "летать не научишься пока не выкинут с гнезда") вот и лечу... Хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение о логике указанной мною выше...

Comment: Вы забыли в список тегов добавить MVC. Почитайте где-нибудь об этом. Надеюсь, что теорию сервлетов вы уже изучили.

Comment: @IgorKudryashov нет, не забыла, все кто связан с разработкой более или менее сталкивался с MVC. Решила, что правила коим является MVC в списке языков будет не уместным)

Comment: Значит про Spring вы уже знаете?

Comment: @IgorKudryashov нет, до него руки не дошли еще

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с использованием JS & AJAX:

1. Молодая девушка заходит на сайт my.mazda.com, сервлет возвращает
   index.jsp
2. Девушка заполняет форму и посредством JavaScript & AJAX
   отправляет желаемый запрос на некий `my.mazda.com/buy`.
3. Обработчик запроса, в вашем случает это сервлет, использует некий слой(обычно
   сервис), который работает с бизнес логикой. Сервис проверяет есть ли
   эти данные? И делает с данными то что нужно, используя ДАО.
4. После чего сервис возвращает сервлету то что у него получилось или не
   получилось. А сервлет, формирует ответ на запрос (П.2)
5. На странице JS & AJAX дожидаются ответа и в зависимости от результата, или
   поздравляет девушку с приобритением новой зеленой мазды, или просит
   выбрать красную.

Вариант без JS & AJAX:

2. Девушка заполняет форму и отправляет желаемый запрос на некий `my.mazda.com/buy`.
3. В зависимости от результата в П.4 или перенаправляем на новую JSP с ошибкой или с поздравлением